# Edit a subsite's home page

Tags: sharepoint-server, sub-site, editing-menu

I have created a subsite and would like to edit the home page, however I can't as the edit page button is greyed out as shown below.

[image]

I have created a permissions level called 'Edit Web Parts' which has the option 'Add and Customize Pages' set and assigned it to my username which also has the 'Full Control' permission level. These permissions are set on the main site and the subsite.

[image]
[image]

Image below shows the permissions on the subsite with the name blacked out, orange is the subsite groups and green the top level sites. I am listed under both owner groups.

[image]

Why can it not edit the subsite's page?

Comment: goto site permissions in that sub site and check your permission in that site.

Comment: I've assigned the permissions to the subsite as well.

Comment: could you please share the screenshot of options you selected for "Edit Web Parts'" permission level and did you check  your permissions in that sub site ?

Comment: Images now added

Comment: goto to the library in which the page is available, try to checkout the file and then try edit page.

Comment: how do I find which library the page is in? I don't see anything in site assets and am not sure where else to look.

Comment: it will be in the page URL, siteassest or site pages ? and also have a look at these links too, https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-cant-edit-the-page-of-a-subsite/8111d792-d5ae-487a-91fa-9e1634b3828f  and  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/90647336-53ac-46a3-84d4-881d3c86cb92/cant-edit-sharepoint-2013-site-page?forum=sharepointadmin

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, home page exists in "Site Pages" library.

Check the URL of your home page, if your page URL is like the following, then your home page exists in "Site Pages" library.

http://your site/subsite/SitePages/Home.aspx

Navigate to the library, Check whether you have full control on the library.

Besides, check whether you have full control on the home page.